# Is there possible in WebStorm to generate callback function code from JSdoc @callback

Tags: javascript, callback, phpstorm, jsdoc, jetbrains-ide

I have defined documentation for function callback using JSDoc @callback:

```
/***
 * My Function description
 * @param {String} myFirstParam My first param
 * @param {File} file My  second pparam
 * @param {MyModule~StandardCallback} cb The callback that handles function result
 */

/**
 * Standard callback.
 * @callback MyModule~StandardCallback
 * @param {Error} err Exception object
 */
```

Webstorm can correctly handle @callback tag: Ctrl + Click on `{MyModule~StandardCallback}` works as "Go To Callback documentation" and `{MyModule~StandardCallback} cb` is shown in Ctrl+Space list. Can WebStorm also generate function expression body with parameter list from this documentation?

Comment: no, there is no such feature. Please feel free to file a request for it to [youtrack](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB)

Comment: All callback arguments can be documented with unit tests